# Difference between the fill methods vs. draw methods in graphics

Tags: java, methods, graphics, difference

```
g.drawRect(50, 50, 400, 75);
g.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 200);
```

Someone told me the first line will draw a rectangle while the second one will draw a square. I understand the parameters, but however wouldn't  `g.drawRect(50,50,200,200);` also draw a square? I thought fill would actually fill the square with a color.

Comment: Can't you just run that code and see what it produces?

Comment: This seems to be off-topic because it is a request for someone else to read the API for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between draw and fill is whether you just get the outline or a "solid" (i.e. filled) shape.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw-java.awt.Shape-

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill-java.awt.Shape-